# Is there way with a SAS data step to add a record count column the increases when a variable changes?

Tags: sas

I have a table which has dates in it and the member changes over time. I want to know when the member started and ended. If the member starts and ends and then restarts that needs to be a different indicator.

Sample of what I have (sorry I don't know how to make a table here):

```
member  yyyymm
Jim  201603
Jim  201606
Jim  201609
Bob  201709
Bob  201712
Jim  201806
Jef  201806
Jef  201809
```

I tried a proc sql statement which finds min and max date but then the max date is wrong if the member restarts (code A below). I also tried a data step and that said it wasn't properly sorted (code B below)

code A

```
proc sql;
create table tst as
select
member,
max(yyyymm) as effective_until,
min(yyyymm) as effective_from
from tbl
group by 1,2;
quit;
```

code B

```
data tst;
count + 1;
by member;
if first.member then count = 1;
run;
```

What I'm hoping for:

```
member  yyyymm  id
Jim  201603  1
Jim  201606  1
Jim  201609  1
Bob  201709  2
Bob  201712  2
Jim  201803  3
Jef  201806  4
Jef  201809  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try the lag function that return parameter from previous call. So here it return the value from last observation (but handle with care). When the member is different from last observation simply change you id. For example by adding 1.

```
data have;
length member $3 yyyymm $6; 
input member yyyymm;
cards;
Jim  201603
Jim  201606
Jim  201609
Bob  201709
Bob  201712
Jim  201806
Jef  201806
Jef  201809
run;

data want;
  set have;
  if lag(member)^=member then id+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sort data=have;
  by yyyymm member;

data want;
  set have;
  by yyyymm member;
if first.member then id+1;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think that every basic structure have to explained. And it should pretty self explain how it works. However not for someone who dosen't know anythink specific about the sas language. But he seems to know first and count + 1 because he use it completly wrong in code B. But maybe he don't know about sorting which is fatal in SAS.

Comment: ok but the code is wrong because the member restart also first.member will every time true